# LINQ prints out sytax instead of result

Tags: c#, linq, console-application, ienumerable

Practicing LINQ and have run into a newbie error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> Customers = new List<string>();
    Customers.Add("Faizan");
    Customers.Add("Ali");
    Customers.Add("Fazeel");
    Customers.Add("Salim");
    Customers.Add("Mueen");
    Customers.Add("Haleem");
    Customers.Add("Mazin");
    Console.WriteLine(Customers.OrderBy(s => s.Length));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I run this and get this as a result in the CMD window:

> System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.Int32]

How do I get it to print out the list according to length?

Comment: the output that you see "System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.Int32]" is not the syntax but the fully qualified name of the type that is returned from the `OrderBy` call. If you put an object into the `Console.WriteLine` method then the `ToString` method will be called and it prints by default the name of the type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<string> Customers = new List<string>();
   Customers.Add("Faizan");
   Customers.Add("Ali");
   Customers.Add("Fazeel");
   Customers.Add("Salim");
   Customers.Add("Mueen");
   Customers.Add("Haleem");
   Customers.Add("Mazin");
   foreach(var customer in Customers.OrderBy(s => s.Length))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(customer);
   }
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The method `OrderBy` takes an object of type `IEnumerable<T>` and converts it to a different `IEnumerable<T>`.

You still have to iterate through each item if you want to do something with each of them.

Answer (score 4):

Other possible solution is that by using `String.Join` instead of `Foreach` loop:

```
List<string> Customers = new List<string>();
Customers.Add("Faizan");
Customers.Add("Ali");
Customers.Add("Fazeel");
Customers.Add("Salim");
Customers.Add("Mueen");
Customers.Add("Haleem");
Customers.Add("Mazin");

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Customers.OrderBy(s => s.Length)));

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: why does this solve the problem? why did the problem arise in the first place? a little more explanation would really improve the quality of your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **foreach loop** to display all data.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      List<string> Customers = new List<string>();
      Customers.Add("Faizan");
      Customers.Add("Ali");
      Customers.Add("Fazeel");
      Customers.Add("Salim");
      Customers.Add("Mueen");
      Customers.Add("Haleem");
      Customers.Add("Mazin");
        var abc = Customers.OrderBy(s => s.Length).ToList();
        foreach (var i in abc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: why does this solve the problem? why did the problem arise in the first place? a little more explanation would really improve the quality of your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
  foreach(var items in Customers.OrderBy(s => s.Length))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(items);
   }
```

Orderby in foreach loop and printout the items.

Comment: why does this solve the problem? why did the problem arise in the first place? a little more explanation would really improve the quality of your answer